# Trouble implementing glightbox in Rails v6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

bit of a newb snag.  I am implementing glightbox in my app.  I had NO trouble sandboxing this in basic HTMLbut when using the same code in my rails app I'm getting the classic:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: GLightbox is not defined
```

I know the script is getting included in the page...I have added console logs and alerts, etc.  The script is def running.  Best I can guess is some conflict with how Rails 6 handles js??  Honestly, no idea and driving me crazy.

Here's how it goes down:

```
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'glightbox' %>


<script>
    var lightbox = GLightbox();
    lightbox.on('open', (target) => {
        console.log('lightbox opened');
    });
    var lightboxDescription = GLightbox({
        selector: '.glightbox2'
    });
    var lightboxVideo = GLightbox({
        selector: '.glightbox3'
    });
    lightboxVideo.on('slide_changed', ({ prev, current }) => {
        console.log('Prev slide', prev);
        console.log('Current slide', current);

        const { slideIndex, slideNode, slideConfig, player } = current;

        if (player) {
            if (!player.ready) {
                // If player is not ready
                player.on('ready', (event) => {
                    // Do something when video is ready
                });
            }

            player.on('play', (event) => {
                console.log('Started play');
            });

            player.on('volumechange', (event) => {
                console.log('Volume change');
            });

            player.on('ended', (event) => {
                console.log('Video ended');
            });
        }
    });

    var lightboxInlineIframe = GLightbox({
        selector: '.glightbox4'
    });

</script>
```

FYI I tried document.ready...same error.  So confused.  The script is literally RIGHT above the failing reference.  Any help would be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested I solved this problem in a strange way.  In the source of glightbox I added the GLightbox = factory() as follows:

```
  (global = global || self, global.GLightbox = factory());
  GLightbox = factory();
```

For whatever reason, in Rails 6, that expression line for global was not resolving correctly.  Once I forced the variable to factory() everything worked as expected.